# Singleton object disposal

Tags: design-patterns, entity-framework-4, singleton, dispose, poco

I've been doing some playing around with POCO objects and EntityFramework. Because of this I have to write my own Context and Repository(s). I would like all repositories to use the same context instance so changes are shared between them. To facilitate this I coded my Context as a Singleton. This way instead of getting a new context and then passing it in the contstructor for all my repositories I can just have the default contstructor get the singleton instance.

My questions are these:

Do I need to dispose of a singleton?

Can I just leave it and rely on garbage collection?

If I need to dispose of it how do I do that?

Is this an acceptable practice or is there some reason I shouldn't use the singleton that I'm not aware of?

Comment: If you make use of an IoC offering such as Unity, it will inject an instance into your constructor for instance, so you don't have to "pass" anything around, as long as that single instance does not hold state information you somehow need.

Answer (score 0):

If you stay leave our class, GC dispose it only when your program will be shutted down. Regarding `Do I need to dispose of a singleton?` this is your personal need. If you wan't to recreate your instance of an object, create DestroyInstance method and set _instance = null there. But I think that Singleton is a realization where your instance must leave always..